# Mono 5.x version on bookworm

Tags: linux, debian, mono

We were looking at updating all our software and architecture as everything is extremely outdated. We updated to Debian 12 bookworm but ran into issues with our application only supporting up to mono 5.x

I've tried setting the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list to :

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mono-official-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-wheezy/snapshots/4.6.2.7 main
```

but whenever I try to do an apt install mono-devel or mono-complete it always defaults to installing 6.8. I believe this is due to the debian bookworm repo having the same priority and the same package as the mono repo but at a later version.

I'm a complete beginner to linux so I was wondering if it's possible to install this old mono version on debian 12 and what I need to do to achieve this.

I tried removing the default debian repo then running an apt update but then I run into a bunch of errors such as

```
Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: That’s very likely to end not well, as you need a lot of guidance than merely a question. Hire an experienced consultant to help review the migration path and rule out huddles please.